# How do I compare hex representation of 2 BigIntegers

Tags: c#, hash, numeric, biginteger, bitcoin

I need to compare sha256 hashes according to bitcoin proof of work algorithm. So the requirement is to create an upper boundary by setting a target difficulty and then create hashes of data + nonce and compare it with upper boundary. If this calculated value is less than upper boundary then it is a valid proof of work.

So that means our upper boundary i.e. `target` can be defined as

```
var target = new BigInteger(1) << 256 - 24
```

And when we create the hash of new block then we compare it with `target`.  i.e.

```
var hashInt = new BigInteger(hashBytes)
if (hashInt.CompareTo(target) == -1) {
    //It is a valid hash
}
```

For this question let’s assume values would be

`target`:

```
6901746346790563787434755862277025452451108972170386555162524223799296
```

`hashInt`:

```
-50765282004551092829298895592266344483300201926640276338429566691241878315064
```

and their hex values would be (which are calculated by calling `.ToString("x")` on these variables)

`target`:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

`hashInt`:

```
8fc3de5d792f2e6b3118697d1e5baa405400e9f8f09625d7eed1481ee0b09fc8
```

Now when we do `hashInt.CompareTo(target) == -1` then it returns `true`. I completely understand why it’s that, but what I want to do is to compare their hex values and if somehow we would be able to do that then on compare it will return `false` which is what I want.

Comment: What do you mean, compare the hex values?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think that you want to compare this numbers by modulo. If so condition `|b| > |a|` will be correct.

Comment: It’s important to know what you’re trying to achieve with this, because some solutions that make sense on integers of fixed size extend only to an idealized representation of `BigInteger`s and not the actual, variable-length one.

Comment: Oh, Bitcoin hashes… you shouldn’t even be using `BigInteger` then. Compare `byte[]`s. (You do get a `byte[]` first, right?)

Comment: @HansPassant BigInteger.CompareTo is not comparing the hex value because if you compare hex values then it should return false

Comment: @Ryan Yes you are right. I am comparing bitcoin hashes but how do you compare if a byte is less or greater than other value? It just tells if they are equal or not

Comment: Do you still want an answer to this? I have one, if you’ll undelete.

Comment: @Ryan undeleted it. I was writing another question with more details on why I am doing this and what is the problem

Comment: Ah, okay. It’s probably best to edit your current question to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare two sequences of equal length with `Zip`:

```
static int CompareSequenceTo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b) where T : IComparable<T> {
    return a
        .Zip(b, (x, y) => x.CompareTo(y))
        .FirstOrDefault(r => r != 0);
}
```

Applied to a difficulty `a` and hash `b`, it correctly reports that `a` is less than `b`:

```
byte[] a = {0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
byte[] b = {0x8f, 0xc3, 0xde, 0x5d, 0x79, 0x2f, 0x2e, 0x6b, 0x31, 0x18, 0x69, 0x7d, 0x1e, 0x5b, 0xaa, 0x40, 0x54, 0x00, 0xe9, 0xf8, 0xf0, 0x96, 0x25, 0xd7, 0xee, 0xd1, 0x48, 0x1e, 0xe0, 0xb0, 0x9f, 0xc8};

Console.WriteLine(a.CompareSequenceTo(b));  // some value less than zero
```

Comment: I've added this and running code. I will let you know and accept your answer if it will work correctly. thanks

Comment: I don't know much about Bitcoin, but I thought hashes in general were only meaningful when compared for equality. Are there any semantics with comparing for greater-than or less-than when it comes to Bitcoin hashes?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: Ideally a hash is like a random value, so if you try a random input you have a certain chance of getting an output less than some other value, determined by that other value. This example requires that the hash have a prefix of 24 zero bits. Since you can treat the first 24 bits of the hash as uniformly random, this corresponds with a probability of 2^−24 (i.e. a 50% chance of mining a block after computing the overall hash function 11.6 million times).

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean 23 zero bits (0x00 0x00 0x01...) or is my understanding wrong?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: That’s the smallest number with only 23 leading zero bits, so anything less than it will have 24.